Why is zero plural?
I saw this sentence in the math textbook.

For example, if we choose two 2s, zero 3s, and one 5, we get the divisor


Here they said zero 3s and one 5.  Two is plural and one is singular, which is obvious, but zero is considered as plural so they said 'zero 3s'. Why is zero plural?
0 = plural, 1 = singular, 2 = plural, 3 = plural, and so on...
--> This relation does not look natural for me.

See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/why-is-zero-followed-by-a-plural-noun

Well, it rolls off the tongue naturally  :-)

Compare More than one person is here with Fewer than two people are here. English is not math.

One interesting context that comes to mind. We usually use no rather than zero as the "quantifier" for a count value of 0. But in casual conversational contexts, it's perfectly possible to say singular 1) He has zero value (he is worth nothing) AND plural 2) He has zero values (he has no moral standards).

@FumbleFingers Is it that with reference to quantities zero is plural, whereas for qualitative measures zero is singular?

@ryang: I've no idea really, but I doubt it. There's no good reason why natural language should enforce any such distinction. Put another way, I know of no reasons why that might be so. To my mind, singular I have no interest in that and plural I have no qualms about that are both "qualitative measures", and it's an absolute certainty many native speakers have come out with both of those utterances using zero rather than no.

Zero is not plural there. It means 3 to the power of zero.  Also, if I say I have zero ideas today, that is not plural either.

If you think what you say "makes sense", and it helps you to remember the "ground truth" (in English, all numeric quantities except exactly one are plural, including zero, fractions, and negative values) then by all means commit it to memory. Personally, I'd have though it's easier to just remember the text in my brackets, which doesn't require any understanding of the difference between quantitative and qualitative. I assume you're just wondering how to express the "rule", rather than trying to figure out which plurality to use in some specific context.

...that's exactly one expressed as one, a, an. Quirky forms like I have exactly one point zero dollars don't fall into the very specific "singular" category. And you can't validly say I have three quarters dollar/s in English, regardless of which plurality you use. It has to be I have three quarters of a dollar (where a and one are interchangeable, but we usually use the formar).

@FumbleFingers Even if anyone actually reads $1.00 as "one point zero zero dollars"—as opposed to "one dollar (and 0 cents)"—thinking of this amount not as a single dollar but as 100 cents (as connoted by that decimal representation) justifies treating it as plural. Hehe.

@ryang: It still looks to me like you're trying various possible ways to avoid recognizing the straightforward rule. It just so happens that one point zero dollars (or one point zero zero, if you want higher precision) can be converted to cents. And you might be able to apply the same reasoning to one point zero zero pounds and thus say the zeroes refer to pence. But that doesn't work if it's a pound weight (divided into 16 ounces, nobody thinks in terms of hundredths of a pound avoirdupois).

'zero 3s'.=NOT PLURAL.

@Lambie 3 to the power of zero is 1, not 0. And "zero ideas" is plural, because "ideas" is plural. "Zero ideas are in his head," not "Zero ideas is in his head."

@JedSchaaf I have zero ideas-ideas is plural. NOT zero. There are zeroes in this answer., That is plural. I am not doing the math. I'm reading what's in the question.

@FumbleFingers In "I know of no reasons" and "I've no qualms" (both plural), "no" indeed just means the quantity 0.  On the other hand, in "I know of no reason" and "There's no good reason" and "I've no interest/[insert qualitative measure]" (all singular), "no" means "not any".

@ryang: I got my degree (in English Language & Literature) half a century ago, but I'm quite certain nobody every formally "taught" me anything about the plurality of zero (as a native Anglophone, I don't need to know such things; like most people, I speak and write my own language perfectly well). But it didn't take me long to phrase my first comment here off the top of my head, and it looks as though the wording suits many others. If you find the quantitative / qualitative distinction helpful, by all means use it. But I doubt it's such a concise and useful universal principle as mine

@FumbleFingers You should reread my previous comment, whose point is not about quantitative-qualitative (which I mentioned once in this thread). And I don't know why you repeatedly believe that we are disagreeing when we aren't. We should delete these two noisy comments.

Ultimately there is no why.

@ryang: Mea culpa if I gave the impression I'm disagreeing with you. Truth be told, I haven't thought through your quantitative / qualitative distinction carefully enough to fully understand the implications in all contexts. I've only really been trying to defend my Everything except exactly one is plural dictum on the grounds that it's "simple" (and if I was a learner, I'd be desperate to find anything about English that could be called "simple"! :) If I've erroneously lumped everything you say into one straightforward quantitative / qualitative distinction, I'm sorry.

@FumbleFingers To be super clear (and I shall stop cluttering this thread after this): (1) from the start, we have been in agreement that generally (regardless of whether the operation ‘minus’ is being applied) the straightforward “rule” is to use the singular form iff the object is read aloud as a single entity (this includes fractional units and qualitative measures); (2) I was additionally pointing out the singular form is of course also used  when "no" is intended to mean "not any" instead of 0.

That is just how the language works. All numbers except exactly 1 are plural. Note that -1 can also be singular, but that depends on the context and dialect.
Examples

0 books
0.1 books
1.5 books
1 book
-1 book (could also be -1 books)
2 books
10 books
-5 books

Please have a look at this answer from English Stack Exchange

1.0 books (?)

-1 is a value but -1 Celsius and -1 book aren't quantities (one is a state while the other means a deficit), so i think it's fine to apply the rule for quantities (which are nonnegative) to objects like -1 book (singular) and -5 books (plural) by disregarding the negativity.

@ryang: I don't think you're doing yourself any favours by trying to force a distinction based on whether the reference is to a "quantity" or a "quality, state, deficit,...". It's zero degrees, minus one degree and minus 0.9 degrees - the presence or absence of minus doesn't affect the basic rule, which has been repeated many times on this page.

@ryang in my dialect (?), I would say "-1 books" in isolation or a ledger. However, I would say "10 books minus 1 book", so it depends on context. MartinBa I would agree with that.

"half a book", no?

@FumbleFingers You’re merely reiterating my point that the 'minus' operation is consistent with that basic "rule" (in my answer below) for quantities: 1 apple is singular, and so is minus 1 apple.    Blarg: Ah, thanks for your input; yea, ultimately, neither "-1 books" nor "¾ litres" would be egregious, after all, said "rule" is observational and subject to dialectal variation.

Fractional quantities less than one seem to depend on how they're phased.  "I read 0.5 ("zero point five") books today, and 1.25 ("one point two five") books yesterday", but "I read half a book and one and a quarter books yesterday." (Both of those sentences feel a little unnatural anyhow.) I think that if the decimal is pronounced, even 1 becomes plural "1.00 books ("one point zero zero books")", but this also feels a bit contrived, too.

@Criggie "a" = 1 -> singular. It's "half (of) one book"

How do you have a negative book?  Is it missing from a library?

@JoshuaTaylor "I read half a book" is multiplying a number (one half) by a singular thing (a book).  It would be this way for "I read ninety percent of a book" or "I read five quarters of a book".  Contrast "I read zero point five books".

@MartinBa, I am quite comfortable with 1.0 gallons per minute. It’s fine in a way that *1 gallons per minute cannot match.

Zero is never plural, because zero is a very useful math concept, namely a placeholder for  nothing, a number that means nothing. just like the idea of 'one' is a placeholder for "something." Does it ever matter how much nothing you have? No. So why is 3 to the power of zero something?   https://medium.com/i-math/the-zero-power-rule-explained-449b4bd6934d

@PaulTanenbaum Just to point out that while “1.0 gallons” is totally natural as it doesn't mean exactly 1 gallon, writing “1.0 books (one point zero books)” rather than “1 book” (unless we mean, say, one book plus 10 out of 80 pages of another book = 1.0125 books = 1.0 books correct to 1 decimal place) is certainly silly, contrived and even paradoxical. For money, though, expressing an exact dollar in decimals isn't unconventional; whether $1.00 ought to be read as "1 point 0 0 dollars" and whether such a reading or 108 cents or 68 dollars goes with "is" or "are" is another topic

Idiomatically, a quantity is singular if and only if it is read aloud as a single entity (like a fractional unit).  Examples:

1 litre is left
¾ litre is left
75% of the cake is left
three-quarters of the cake is left

1.0 litres (e.g., 1.003 litres to 1 decimal place) are left
0 litres are left
1¾ litres are left
0.75 litres are left
three-quarters of the pieces of cake are left
3 quarters of the cake (3 quarter-cake slices) are left


(notice that 0.75 litres—unlike ¾ litre and 75% of the cake—is not read aloud as a fractional part of a whole). This observation for quantities (which are by definition nonnegative) holds regardless of whether the operation ‘minus’ is being applied; that is, “-1 litre” and “-¾ litre” (whatever these mean) are correct.
When a plural quantity is being thought of as a single amount, it goes with a singular verb:

24 hours is all I need
0.75 litres / 2 litres is not a lot
one point zero zero dollars / 3 dollars is a nominal fee.

P.S. Note that “I have no legs” means that I have 0 legs (as opposed to 1 leg or 2 legs), while “I have no leg” means that I have not any leg (i.e., I do not have any leg).
P.P.S. Noting that “crew” can be singular or plural, the choice between “half the crew is” and “half the crew are” is a matter of intended meaning/emphasis.

Note that when we say half a kilo, the "numeric quantifier" attaches to a (replaceable in that context by of one). We always include [of] a / one between a fractional value and the "thing being counted / quantified" in speech, even if we don't always write it.

@FumbleFingers Yes, so we say 0.5 kilograms and 1½ kilograms, but say ½ kilogram. I've just added an addendum to try to explain this.

Your amendment was good. I hope you don't mind, but I added (one) after whole in your text, to emphasize the point. (After casting the well-deserved upvote! :)

I'd say that expressing it as a fraction isn't fundamentally the reason for the singular - it's because you're using "of". "Three-fourths" isn't actually grammatically quantifying "liter", as you can see by the intervening article. So "three-fourths of a liter" is the same type of expression as "most of a liter" or even "the weight of a liter".

@Deusovi Yes, it's not the presence of the fraction ¾ per se that makes "¾ litre" singular (otherwise we'd incorrectly say "1¾ litre"), but the fact that we are discussing a fraction of a whole.  ("Most of a litre" and "the weight of a litre" are good examples too—thanks!—but fall outside the scope of my answer, which is discussing quantities with explicit values.)

Right, I'm just pointing out that there's an underlying grammatical reason for the distinction. The "a fraction" part isn't directly relevant to the rule; it's just the "of a whole" part.  The actual numerical modifier is "a", and "three fourths" is just playing the exact same grammatical role that "most" or "the weight" would. (The fraction-ness is only relevant because raw fractions aren't allowed as determiners, so we're forced to use the "of" construction.)

@Deusovi Three times of a whole isn't singular, whereas a fraction of a whole is.

There are two different singular/plural statuses that I think are being conflated here. In "Three times of a whole", "three" is quantifying "times" (making it plural), and "a" is quantifying "whole" (making it singular). The plurality of these two parts is entirely independent. You've given examples of PL-SG and SG-SG; we can also say "a quarter of two thousand balloons" (SG-PL) or "three quarters of two thousand balloons" (PL-PL).

I think there's also an aspect of whether fractions of a whole represent countable quantities or not - consider "Half the milk is needed for this recipe" versus "Half the workers are needed for this task."

@NuclearHoagie "Half the workers" isn't a fraction of a/one whole.          Deusovi: I don't disagree with your examples at all; however, in our current context the entirety of the phrase "a fraction of a whole" is pertinent, rather than just the fragment "of a whole".

It's pertinent semantically, but not grammatically. When you say "a whole", you've already decided that the last word is singular. The preceding part has its own, independent plurality (one quarter/bite/slice [SG] of a cake; three quarters/bites/slices [PL] of a cake), and the "of ..." part doesn't matter for determining that.

@ryang What defines "a whole" then? We can certainly speak about the workers collectively, e.g., "the workers have gone to lunch". I don't really see why "the workers" isn't a whole but "the crew" would be, suggested by the singularity of "half the crew is needed for this task".

@NuclearHoagie Workers are multiple wholes, that's why we say "the workers have gone to lunch" and rightly don't say "half the workers is". On the other hand, "crew" could either be singular or plural, and if treating it as singular, then it is indeed correct to say "half the crew is".

I'm pretty sure I would say "three-quarters of a litre are needed" not "is needed". After all, we are referring to multiple quarters, not one. I would say one quarter of a litre is needed, but not three.

@terdon After taking a bite, three-quarters of my apple remains. I then slice it into three equal pieces; now three quarters of my original apple (so, three quarter-apples) are on the table.

Dammit, @ryang, yes, exactly! That's how I would say it too and I don't know why I would make the first singular but the second plural. That's really intriguing.

@terdon "I don't know why I would make the first singular but the second plural." As explained in my answer above: hyphenating the plural "three (3) quarters of an apple" makes it become a single (albeit partial) object.

Well no. As a native speaker, the singular doesn't work for me in the three-quarters of a litre is* needed example but it does in After taking a bite, three-quarters of my apple remains (although I would also be happy with remain here) and I can't put my finger on why.

@terdon The difference is this: the number of litres is a (continuous) measurement, while the number of apples is a (discrete) count. However, I claim that in each case, a fractional unit is singular; yes we are agreeing to disagree.

"three quarters of my apple remains" Plural, because "quarters" are collections of 4, of which 3 remain. How many percents is this? 75 percent, because percent is the singular name we give for amounts in hundredths.

Zero is not plural. The plural of zero is "zeroes" as in "The score for the team today is zeroes all across the board." (Baseball)
But when zero is used as an adjective to modify something countable the word it modifies is expressed in the plural. Examples from other answers are "zero books", "zero liters", and your own example, "zero 3s".
The reason for this is that zero is not one. In English usage, all numbers but one, when used as modifiers, throw the noun that is modified into the plural. We have no way to express a zero amount of a thing, only a singular way and a plural way, and since it is not singular, it is plural.
This is true also in other words that express negation. We say, "There are no ducks on the pond" and "None of the light bulbs are working." There is no noun form to represent a zero number, only singular and plural.

They're not talking about the word "zero", they're talking about the number zero (0), so the whole first paragraph is irrelevant.

The first paragraph is only to clarify the question. The question is about zero used as an adjective, not a noun.

It seems natural to me. Note that you say “I met no cats today.” No cats, one cat, two cats...
(Though in the Lord of the Rings, Eowyn says “I am no man.” https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7_c-R7i8F4)

To add: notice that you'd also say that this cat has no tail, meaning that this cat has not any tail rather than that this cat has 0 tails.

@ryang note that this seems to do with the expectation of the "usual amount" of the thing in question - if cats were expected to have anywhere from 1 to multiple tails, you would say "the cat has no tails". We say "this person has no right leg" as humans only have one of each, but for a cat we would say "this cat has no right legs". I am not 100 sure of the formal reasons, but I think it is because in the singular case we refer to the specific item that can be either present or not - either it has the state "a tail" or "no tail".

@htmlcoderexe Precisely. “I have no legs” means that I have 0 legs (as opposed to 1 leg or 2 legs), while “I have no leg” means that I have not any leg. Both sentences are grammatical.

"I am no man" means "I am not a man" (hence singular) not "I am zero men" (plural zero).

Similarly, David Byrne sings "This ain't no disco" (singular) in "Life During Wartime". ;)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@JasonOrendorff David Byrne example is an idiom meaning "This is not a disco!" Emphasis added via double negation, which is not grammatical in English.

@ryang The sentence "I have no leg." is like Chomsky's "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously." Parses but is meaningless without further context. Use that sentence and most english speakers would indicate that it is a non sequitur ( does not follow. Eg: "wtf?" "huh?" "I beg your pardon?" "What?"

"I have no leg", unlike "colorless green ideas sleep furiously", is meaningful: a native english speaker might merely be surprised at that utterance and suspect its meaning to be figurative. Technically, neither sentence, per se, is a non sequitur.

The problem is that "s" designates a plural, while "apostrophe (”'")s" represents a possessive. In the example offered, "3's" represents a category of numerals characterized by the symbol 3 have a property that they possess of zero or one or two that is, no 3's, one "3" (3), or two "3's" (3,3).

No, that is not the problem.  For one thing, there are no occurrences of "3's" in the example offered.  But more importantly, although "3's" could be used to describe properties of the number three or of a numeral 3, that is not how it is used in the example.  The number of factors of 3 in the number 20 is not a property possessed by the number three or numeral 3.  At best, your "no 3's, one "3" (3), or two "3's" (3,3)" improperly reverses the direction of possession: 20's (note possessive) prime factors include two 2s, zero 3s, and one 5.
